# How to remove Request Body Examples Dropdown in swagger-php

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-php, swagger-3.0

I'm using `Swagger 3.0` in tandem with `swagger-php` and getting

### strange behavior with request body markup

.

In the image, the "Examples:" dropdown shows up and "Example Value | Schema" shows up under that dropdown instead of "Example Value | Model".

My questions are:

1. How do I remove the examples dropdown?
2. How do I add multiple examples for the dropdown?
3. Why does my `sagger-ui show` "Example value | Schema" instead of
   "Example value | Model"?
4. Is there updated documentation that's not listed about Request Body
   examples?

I'm following the post example on line 40 of

https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore-3.0/controllers/User.php

https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore-3.0/models/RequestBody.php

https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore-3.0/models/User.php

Here's my markup:

```
/**
* @OA\Post(
*     path="/exampleUrl/{y2k}",
*     description="Description",
*     summary="Summary",
*     @OA\Parameter(
*         name="y2k",
*         in="path",
*         description="Parameter Description",
*         required=true,
*         example="bbop",
*         @OA\Schema(
*           type="string",
*         )
*     ),
*     @OA\RequestBody(ref="#/components/requestBodies/RequestBodyExample"),
*     @OA\Response(
*         response="200",
*         description="Response Description",
*     ),
* )
*/

/**
* @OA\RequestBody(
*     request="RequestBodyExample",
*     description="Request Body Description",
*     required=true,
*     @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/schemas/SchemaExample"),
* )
*/

/**
* @OA\Schema()
*/
class SchemaExample
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @OA\Property()
     */
    public $exampleString;

}
```

[Examples dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqcNU.png)

Comment: It's a [bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5455) in Swagger UI - see the linked Q&A for details.

Comment: Myth busted, TYVM!

Comment: This bug was fixed in Swagger UI 3.23.2.